# Trouble rendering HTML from Rustbook Web Server

Tags: html, rust, webserver

I am fllowing [Rust Book Web Server Tutorial](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch20-01-single-threaded.html) in chapter 20 of the rust Book and am having issues rendering the HTML. The code I have is exactly the same for handling a connection as the tutorial:

```rust
fn handle_connection(mut stream: TcpStream) {
    let buf_reader = BufReader::new(&mut stream);
    let http_request: Vec<_> = buf_reader
        .lines()
        .map(|result| result.unwrap())
        .take_while(|line| !line.is_empty())
        .collect();
    let status_line = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n";
    let contents = fs::read_to_string("hello.html").unwrap();
    let length = contents.len();

    let response = format!("{status_line}\r\nContent-Length: {length}\r\n\r\n{contents}");

    stream.write_all(response.as_bytes()).unwrap();
}
```

With hello.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
    <p>Hi from Rust</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Running the server and making a request on the web displays the actual html code:
[image]

I wondered if the indentation of my HTML was an issue, but my vscode extension automatically formats it this way so I assumed it must be ok.

Instead of the HTML being rendered as the tutorial shows:

[image]

I am using Brave browser as well. I am lost as to what could be going wrong. Assuming the tutorial is correct, I would appreciate any pointers as I am fairly new to Rust and brand new to web servers and HTML!

Comment: Looks like you have too many line breaks between "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" and "Content-Length"? Note that in Listing 20-5, it has `let status_line = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK";` (no extra \r\n)

Answer (score -1):

you just forgot to add `Content-Type: text/html` header into response.

Here is working code:

```rust
fn handle_connection(mut stream: TcpStream) {
    let buf_reader = BufReader::new(&mut stream);
    let http_request: Vec<_> = buf_reader
        .lines()
        .map(|result| result.unwrap())
        .take_while(|line| !line.is_empty())
        .collect();

    let status_line = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
    let content_type = "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";
    let contents = fs::read_to_string("hello.html").unwrap();
    let response = format!(
        "{status_line}{content_type}Content-Length: {length}\r\n\r\n{contents}",
        status_line = status_line,
        content_type = content_type,
        length = contents.len(),
        contents = contents
    );

    stream.write_all(response.as_bytes()).unwrap();
}
```

Comment: A `Content-Type` header is not required for this to work.